# How can I stop Google Chrome from prioritizing search results over previously visited websites?

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-search, search-engines

The latest version of Google Chrome (74?) seems to have changed the search bar's behavior. It now lists search suggestions before previously visited websites.

I find this annoying and want it to work like it did before. How can I revert the search bar to the old behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to chrome://flags/#omnibox-drive-suggestions
2. Set **Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions** to `Disabled`
3. Restart the browser to apply the changes.